# Gerrit workflow - no new changes

Tags: git, gerrit

I am currently having some problems with our gerrit workflow. I have pushed some code for review but the review has been rejected with a -1 and I need to submit another patchset to this same review.

I am doing the following and having some problems:

1. git fetch [repo] refs/changes/93/493/1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
2. 3 files: A, B, C are part of the commit
3. based upon the review I make changes to A
4. git add A (to stage the new version)
5. git commit --amend --all (the changeId remains the same - files A, B, C)
6. git push review

I am getting the error:

! [remote rejected] master -> refs/for/master (no new changes)

Can someone explain to me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit would only answer that if the two commits (the current patch set on gerrit and the local HEAD) where the same. Are you sure you've made changes to any files and commited them?

You can find the two SHA-1's like this:

- in gerrit look for "Patch set 1
- locally `git log -n1`

Comment: I am trying to update a file that is already part of the commit. I have edited the above question to try and make it more clear.

Comment: Did you try to compare the SHA-1 between gerrits patch set 1 and your HEAD after the fix?